# Different behavior of UISearchBar with XIB and code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am unable to understand the behavior of `UISearchBar`'s bar tint property.

I am enclosing a screenshot of my simulator output.

[image]

The first search bar was done in XIB. It basically consists of a `UISearchBar` inside a `UIView`. The `UIView`'s background is set to red color and `UISearchBar`'s bar tint color has been set to clear color. Everything else is default. I am attaching the screenshot of XIB. This is what I am trying to achieve by means of code.

[image]

I tried working by code in all combinations and in no way I am able to get what I got through XIB. In the first attempt by code, I am just rewriting the stuff what I did by XIB. But I get a black colored search bar as shown in simulator. In the second attempt by code, I am setting the bar tint color to red color, but I am getting black line on border.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 64)];
searchBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 320, 44)];
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
[self.view addSubview:searchBarView];

UIView *searchBarView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 64)];
searchBarView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UISearchBar *searchBar2 = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 320, 44)];
[searchBar2 setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[searchBarView2 addSubview:searchBar2];
[self.view addSubview:searchBarView2];
}
```

1) How is that my first attempt by code though similar with XIB, yet gives me totally different result? What am I missing?

2) By my second attempt by code, how do I get rid of the black line?